# Does Boost: named_mutex requires disk IO?

Tags: boost, ipc

This must be a silly question, but nowhere could I found the answer:

Does Boost's `named_mutex` (and other `named*` facilities) require any disk IO?

I know it's not supposed to be put into the shared memory, that's fine.

However implementation-wise, will it stress my disk, or I can count on it?

This is the boost class reference: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html

I know it's depending on the platform and other details, I need this answer for an up-2-date (Bullseye) Debian-based Linux.

Writing anything to `/tmp` or `/dev/shm` doesn't count as DiskIO, as they're  *tmpfs* by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian, the implementation will be `shm` based.

On windows there will be similar kernel namespaces, without disk access.

If you wish, you can `strace` and `ltrace` to quickly check for IO patterns.

Comment: Thanks, I was just realized that files are getting created in `/dev/shm`.